# i try filter array base on search input and select menu

Tags: javascript, filter

I'm trying to make filter base on input search and select menu at the same time.The filter works for select and search but separately if I try marge I don't have any errors output but the filter doesn't work...

```
(zemlja.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) === 0)
```

if I remove this from filter, filter will work for select menu but I want to make one filter for search and select

```
const selectFilter = zemlje.filter((zemlja) => {
    if ((zemlja.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) === 0) || (select === 'All') 
         || (zemlja.region === select)) return true;
});
```

Comment: `.indexOf(search) === 0` wouold mean string starts with query word. Try `.indexOf(search) >= 0` as query can exist anywhere

Comment: @Rajesh - Or `.includes(search)` for [recent enough browsers](https://caniuse.com/#feat=array-includes).

Comment: i try don't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect the results to contain the search-string and pass the filter-criteria, which is why I would use `&&`:

```
const selectFilter = zemlje.filter((zemlja) => {
  const searchHit = (zemlja.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) === 0);
  const filterPass = ((select === 'All') || (zemlja.region === select));
  if ( searchHit && filterPass ) return true;
  return false;
});
```

Comment: hey man its work :) thanks i spend some time and u really help me